# Do not fire one event if already fired another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a code like this:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(e) {
   //do something
});

$('form input').on('change', function(e) {
  //do some other things
));
```

First and second events do actually the same things with the same input field, but in different way. The problem is, that when I click the `#foo` element - form change element fires as well. I need form change to fire always when the content of input is changing, but not when `#foo` element is clicked.

That's the question )). How to do this?

Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QhXyj/1/

Comment: I agree, click shouldn't trigger change on same element.

Comment: @charlietfl: It does. If you click somewhere else, focus changes, and when an input element is blurred a `change` might fire

Comment: @bergi but really shouldn't be a change on the same input that is clicked is my point. Yes a change on prior input that was in focus

Comment: @charlietfl: OK, yes, but that happens neither. If you click on a focused element, it doesn't fire a change event - it just might change the caret.

Comment: @Bergi  now that a fiddle with some code was added I can see the situation...originally no code was provided and issue wasn't clear and neither was wording

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that onChange fires when the focus leaves the #input. In your case, this coincides with clicking on the button. Try pressing Tab, THEN clicking on the button.

To handle this particular case, one solution is to delay the call to the `change` event enough check if the button got clicked in the meantime. In practice 100 milisecond worked. Here's the code:

```
$().ready(function() {

    var stopTheChangeBecauseTheButtonWasClicked = false;
    $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
        stopTheChangeBecauseTheButtonWasClicked = true;
        $('#wtf').html("I don't need to change #input in this case");
    });

    $('#input').on('change', function(e) {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function doTheChange() {
            if (!stopTheChangeBecauseTheButtonWasClicked) {
                $(self).val($(self).val() + ' - changed!');
            } else {
                stopTheChangeBecauseTheButtonWasClicked = false;
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

And the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/QhXyj/11/

Comment: There's a coincidence of events, onChange happens when #input loses focus. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It works for me, but I cannot force users first to unfocus input and only then click the button.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do now; check the updated answer!

Comment: I thought to do this way, but I hoped there is more beautiful solution, without timeouts. But it works :). Thank you! )

Comment: It's an interesting question. I've upvoted it and I'm curious if someone can find a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's only natural that a change event on a blurred element fires before the clicked element is focused. If you don't want to use a timeout ("do something X ms after the input was changed unless in between a button was clicked", as proposed by Dan) - and timeouts are ugly - you only could go doing those actions twice. After the input is changed, save its state and do something. If then - somewhen later - the button is clicked, retrieve the saved state and do the something similar. I guess this is what you actually wanted for your UI behaviour, not all users are that fast. If one leaves the input (e.g. by pressing `Tab`), and then later activates the button "independently", do you really want to execute both actions?

```
var inputval = null, changedval = null;

$('form input').on('change', function(e) {
    inputval = this.value;
    // do some things with it and save them to
    changedval = …
    // you might use the value property of the input itself
));

$('#foo').on('click', function(e) {
    // do something with inputval
});

$('form …').on('any other action') {
    // you might want to invalidate the cache:
    inputval = changedval;
    // so that from now on a click operates with the new value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form input').on('change', function(e) {
  // don't do the thing if the input is #foo
  if ( $(this).attrib('id') == 'foo' ) return;

  //do some other things
));
```

**UPDATE**

How about this:

```
$().ready(function() {

    $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#wtf').html("I don't need to change #input in this case");
    });

    $('#input').on('change', function(e) {
        // determine id #input is in focus
        if ( ! $(this).is(":focus") ) return;

        $(this).val($(this).val()+' - changed!');
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {


          $('#button').on('click', function() {
              //use text() not html() here
              $('#wtf').text("I don't need to change #input in this case");
          }); 

          //fire on blur, that is when user types and presses tab
          $('#input').on('blur', function() {
              alert("clicked"); //this doesn't fire when you click button
              $(this).val($(this).val()+' - changed!');
          });  
      });​
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhXyj/7/)

Comment: The same story :(. In your Fiddle blur event still fires when I click the button.

Comment: It doesn't. I've added an alert() inside blur and updated the fiddle.

Comment: It doesn't when the input field is empty. But if I type something, and then click the button - alert still works.

Comment: That's the nature of blur() event, it is invoked as soon as you remove the focus from the input.